# Можно ли создать глобальный класс для конфигурации ApplicationContxt в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, di

Подскажите можно ли создать глобальный класс конфигурации для ApplicationContext в Spring вместо того что бы использовать вот такой вот пример:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
Company company = (Company) context.getBean("company");
```

И если можно то как это можно получать потом в приложении вместо .getBean();?

Comment: Если спринг стартовал, то у него уже есть контекст, так что создавать ещё один нет надобности.

Comment: @Roman C то есть каждый раз когда мне нужно получить элемент из контекста мне необходимо создавать объект контекста и после с помощью метода .getBean(); получать нужный мне?

Comment: Нет как раз этого делать не надо, а лучше повесить  слушателя на инициализация контекста

Comment: Можно попросить какой то пример, или ресурс с примером, что бы понятнее было?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire, в двух словах - вас интересует аннотация @Autowired

Comment: @Roman C и если создать такого слушателя, то как можно будет получить объект из контекста?

Comment: Объект можно получить стандартным способом, а вот контекст только после загрузки спринга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь получить бин таким образом, до в 99 процентах это  свидетельствует о том, что Вы неправильно подходите к использованию спринга. Используя спринг, логика Вашего приложения, не должна выходить за пределы бинов.
Рассмотрим для примера классическое приложение,содержащее 3 основных класса/интерфейса.

```
@Controller 
public class CustomWebController {
@Autowired
private CustomService customService;
}

@Service 
public class CustomService {
@Autowired
private CustomRepository customRepository;
}

@Repository
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomModel, Long>{
}
```

У нас есть веб-контроллер (CustomRepository  - для обработки запросов), сервис (CustomService  - наша бизнес-логика), репозиторий(CustomRepository  - опреации с БД).
Все это бины, поскольку помечены соответсвующими аннотациями. Поэтому спринг при запуске приложения по умолчанию создаст из них объекты (все синглтоны) и поместит в свой контейнер.
Теперь, когда на Ваш контроллер поступит запрос, поскольку контроллер является бином, вы можете объявить переменную типа класса сервисного уровня , которую спринг сможет инициализировать, используя контейнер (поместит в нее заранее созданный соответсвующий ,бин-синглтон CustomService). Для этого вы можете использовать конструктор, аннотацию autowired (как в примере) и т.д. (это уже к вопросу о способах инициализации). 
Как Вы можете заметить, в классе CustomService объявлена переменная типа CustomRepository, над которой имеется аннотация Autowired. Поэтому спринг проинициализирует и эту переменную, поместив в не экземпляр CustomRepository. 
Вместе с тем, если в классе-контроллере вы вместо того, чтобы проинциализировать переменную с помощью аннотации Autowired, создадите экземпляр класса CustomService с помощью оператора new (CustomService customService = new CustomService();), то переменная CustomRepository в экземпляре данного класса не будет проинциализирована спрингом. Это происходит потому, что экземпляр класса получен через new, а не из контейнера спринга, соответсвенно, спринг ничего не знает об этом конкретном экземпляре класса и не сможет проинициализировать переменные в нем. Это случай, когда Ваша логика вышла за пределы спринга и теперь Вам требуется конструкция, которая напаисана в Вашем вопросе. Именно поэтому это и некорректно. 
И еще, создавайте спринг-приложение с помощью этого сайта https://start.spring.io/ (либо через спец меню в среде разработки). Вы увидите , что спринг записывает в методе main, чтобы инициализировать приложение.
Надеюсь, что это прояснит ситуацию, а если нет, то задавайте вопросы.

Comment: да, это розъяснило немного. Только хотел еще уточнить по поводу использования конструкторов, что бы иницыализировать поля в конструкторах, необходимо использовать классы конфигураций, в которых использовать бины, вот так вот?
https://ideone.com/hMxV1G

Comment: нет, классы конфигураций тут не причем, хотя класс с аннотацией configuration - тоже бин, как и метод, обозначенный как bean  (при этом имя бина - это имя метода, а сам бин  - это экземпляр класса, который соответствует возвращаемому значению метода). вы должны понимать, что по сути бин это обычный класс с геттерами , сеттерами и конструктором по умолчанию. эти требования нужны для того, чтобы спринг мог создать экземпляр этого класса.

Comment: Это обусловлено тем, что создание бина происходит рефлексивно, а не через new, соответсвенно, если такового констурктора не будет, то сприрнг не сможет создать экземпляр класса и поместить его в свой контейнер, ведь в этом случае конструктор может принимать какие угодно и сколько угодно параметров, заранее это знать никак нельзя. гетеры и сеттеры позволяют работать с полями класса(это понятно). но с конструкторами есть одно исключение: если вы в конструктор запишите класс, кроторый также является бином, то спринг без проблем воспользуется этим конструктором,хотя дефолтный конструктор отсутвует

Comment: Например, есть бины - класс А и класс Б. у Б есть дефолтный конструктор, а у класса А единственный конструктор принимает Б. В этом случае ошибки не будет, потому что спринг видит в конструкторе класса А класс Б, который также является бином, соответсвенно , сначала будет проинициализирован класс Б, а уже потом с его помощью класс А. Разумеется , в классе А есть переменная типа класса Б, которая и должна быть проинициализированна. Так и выполняется инициализация через конструктор.

Comment: То есть вся инициализация происходит только с помощью аннотации Autowired? Не важно конструктор это, или просто поле, то необходимо это делать только с помощью аннотации?

Comment: Нет. Прочитайте еще раз. Класс А содержит перменную типа класса Б. Там нет никакой аннотации. Конструктор класса А выглядит так: А (Б б) {this.б = б;}